# Adding a new project to Sonar v.2.9

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonar to review my code for a java project. the version that I am using is v.2.9, I am using sonar for the first time. I have no idea how to add project in sonar server.
Please help on this

Thanks.

Comment: which is your build tool? Maven? Maven has a sonar plugin.. if you are using ant - try this link http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-2-6-adds-continuous-inspection-support-for-ant-community/#more-4887

Comment: ya.. I am using maven... but wanted to know how to add a project to sonar if i dont want to use any plugin or any other build tool.

Comment: I am not sure if you can add projects to SONAR without a build tool.. From the docs it seems as if it needs some build tool to run the SONAR scripts..

Comment: running mvn:sonar is the easiest way to go..

Comment: Sonar identifies each project using a unique key. In Maven this is a combination of the Maven groupid and artifact id. So run a fresh analysis and if the project doesn't already exist it will be created automatically.

Answer (score 18):

There's no option to "add" a project in Sonar from Sonar UI. Projects are automatically added to Sonar whenever a successful analysis occurs. 
I'd suggest you the following :

1. Upgrade to a more recent Sonar version. http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/
2. Read the [analyzing source code guide](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code) where you can find instructions for all available methods to trigger a new analysis

`Update` : Sonarqube allows (I think after 5.x version) provisioning of projects as described in their [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Existence)

Comment: Hi, I have sonar and maven installed on two different host. Would the command mvn sonar:sonar work?? Is there anywhere in maven I need to define the url of sonar or any other update in pom.xml??

Comment: Yes you can, but you still haven't read the instructions : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven

Answer (score 12):

With Administrator role, you can "Provision" a project.

1. Log in as administrator
2. Select `Settings` from the menu
3. Select `System` -> `Provisioning` from the sub-menu
4. Click `Create` (at the very far right of the frame)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty straight forward with the newest version. All you have to do is installing as the guide. And it will prompt a command which you need to execute with your build tool at the project folder.

For an example for maven it would be like

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=4aa32e977ab1513e3fe5c3ac0c7883528d01a5e8.
```

With a command similar to this reports will be sent to the Sonarqube. And code analysis will be done